# Linkedin Member Profile : profile is not showing on my website

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api, linkedin-plugins

I have a linkedin profile with below public URL 
https://www.linkedin.com/in/col-rs-bhandari-veteran-2706a612

and using below script code to show it on my website.

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/col-rs-bhandari-veteran-2706a612" data-format="hover" data-text="Col RS Bhandari (Veteran)"></script>
```

But there is nothing on the page. Also no error in firebug. I tried with another profile and it is working fine with other profile. Is there anything in profile I need to setup?

I have checked all parameters checked in Public Profile.